# Help with hash tables and quadratic probing in Java

Tags: java, insert, find, hashtable, quadratic-probing

I really need help with inserting into a hash table.  I'm just not totally getting it right now.  Could someone explain quadratic and linear probing in layman's terms?

```
public void insert(String key)
{
    int homeLocation = 0;
    int location = 0;
    int count = 0;

    if (find(key).getLocation() == -1)  // make sure key is not already in the table
    {
       //****** ADD YOUR CODE HERE FOR QUADRATIC PROBING  ********
    }
}
```

This is the code I'm working on.  I'm not asking anyone to do it, I just really need help with learning the whole concept

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing? What are you having problems with?

Answer (score 3):

First of all we are talking about an *open addressing* (or *closed hashing*) approach. You need to handle collisions calculating a new hashcode if the previous one is already used by another one, this because every bucket of the hashamap can contain at most 1 element.

So you have an hashing function with two parameters:

- `v`, the value of the object used to compute hashcode.
- `t`, it's `i*f` where `i`, called *stepsize*, is what you add everytime to you hash function if a collision occur and `f` is the number of collisions reached so far.

Starting from this you have two possible functions:

```
H(v, t) = (H(v) + t) % n
H(v, t) = (H(v) + c*t + d*t*t) % n
```

First one is a *linear function*, while second is a *quadratic one* (here it comes the names of this tecnique).. where you should know what `% n` is, `c` and `d` are chosen constants to have a better hashfunction..

Practically speaking for linear probing:

- you caculate `H(x, 0)`
- - if cell is free place the element there
- - if cell is occupied calculate `H(x, i)`
- - - if cell is free place the element in the new address
- - - if cell is occupied then calculate `H(x, i+i)`
- - - - continue until you find an empty cell

for the *quadratic probing* what you do is identical, you start from `H(x,0)`, then `H(x,i)` then `H(x,i+i)`, what differs is the hashing function involved which will give a different weight to the step size.

Comment: Actually you helped me out a lot..im not at my desk right now to peek at my work but i understand it way more